# RSSI information with Scapy

Tags: python, wifi, scapy, rssi

When I try to get Rssi information from my around wireless network with Scapy , I'm getting some error. Also , I am using ALFA-036NH , my monitor mode is open and OS is Kali Linux. I used below codes :

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime
import os
import signal
import sys
def PacketHandler(pkt) :
  if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
    if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8 :
      if pkt.haslayer(Dot11Beacon) or pkt.haslayer(Dot11ProbeResp):
        try:
            extra = pkt.notdecoded
            rssi = -(256 - ord(extra[-4:-3]))
        except:
            rssi = -100
        print "WiFi signal strength:", rssi

sniff(iface="wlan0mon", prn = PacketHandler)
```

However, all of networks giving -100 dbm. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Please retry using the latest [scapy github version](https://github.com/secdev/scapy) (or 2.4.1+). It has improved support for RSSI, which is now available (if present), via the `dBm_AntSignal` field.

```
pkt.dBm_AntSignal
```

[image: Screenshot]

You don’t need the function you provided.

PS: where did you find such code ? Did you do it yourself? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to get rssi quality from python but your comments is a helper for just controlling am I right sir ?

Comment: Sorry I don’t really understand what you mean :/