# Wireless signal strength from scapy using python3

Tags: python-3.7, scapy, signal-strength

Trying to retrieve wireless signal strength using a python tool and scapy. the output for all networks come out as -100. Here is a section of the code.

```
try:
            extra = frame.notdecoded
            rssi = (256 - ord(extra[-3:-2]))
        except:
            rssi = -100
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Scapy 2.4.1+ and use

```
rssi = frame[RadioTap]. dBm_AntSignal
```

See the doc: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.dot11.html#scapy.layers.dot11.RadioTap

(Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918918/5459467)